# How can I close background processes from my Android app?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application. How can I close a background process like a music player or video player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android 2.2 and above you can only kill background processes.  If you want to kill a background process you can use the following:

```
private ActivityManager actman = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
actman.killBackgroundProcesses("com.root.package");
```

also your android manifest must include the permission:

`android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES`